# Anchor link to open jquery mobile popups just redirects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

I previously used javascript dialogs for confirmation on a mobile web app, but am now trying to switch over to using the new popups feature in JQM 1.2.  My initial test doesn't work - no popup appears and I'm simply redirected to the anchor I'm trying to call.

My test code is simple, albeit a bit obfuscated because I'm using haml:

```
%a{:href => "#popupBasic", :"data-rel" => "popup"} Show popup
%div{:id => "popupBasic", :"data-role" => "popup"} Basic popup div
```

That said, I don't believe the haml is causing the issue based on reading the final HTML output.  Both elements are at equal depth and contained within the  element.

In addition, the div does "popup" without issue when I use the following at the console:

```
$( "#popupBasic" ).popup( "open" )
```

That makes me believe that the issue lies somewhere in the link or the URL handling.  When I do click the link, it instead takes me straight to

```
http://localhost:3000/#popupBasic
```

Any ideas on how I should be handling the URL differently so that it shows the popup as intended?

Comment: script should return false or prevent link redirection in other way http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: Sounds like your functions are not getting bound to the `DIV` properly or there is some other error preventing JS to load. Are you seeing any errors when the page loads? Are other JS/JQM elements working when you test this?

Comment: @AnatoliyKukul I'm not certain what you're suggesting - I'm not actually writing any custom JS, just attempting to use the out-of-the-box JQM.  I was only using popup() as a method of testing to make sure  that function was even initialized.

Comment: @Twisty I'm seeing no errors in the console.  I am using the minified JS at the moment, but if you can suggest where in the JQM code I should be looking then I can switch to the uncompressed version and add some breakpoints.

Comment: I don't use haml, so I can't really say for sure. I made the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/Bp7QF/ to using the JQM Example. Is your resulting HTML like this?

Comment: Hey @Twisty thanks for your help - once I started using jsfiddle, I was able to pinpoint the problem and I'll add it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After realizing the problem was probably some part of my Javascript, I went through and tried turning off each bit of javascript individually, until I figured out that the problem was with this in my application.js file:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
  $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
});
```

which prevents all anchor click handling.  Obviously now that I've removed this code the anchor links are working properly.  Of course, that means I'm now left with trying to figure out why I added that in the first place and what I just broke by removing it...

Comment: Good deal. Glad you were able to find it. Don't think anyone would have been able to answer that for you, lack of application.js for us.